# C++ Simple circular reference and forward declaration issue

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2015, include, forward-declaration

I get this error:

> error C3646: 'bar': unknown override specifier

when trying to compile this very simple C++ code in Visual Studio 2015:

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "Foo.h"

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Foo.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include "Bar.h"

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();

    Bar bar;
};
```

**Bar.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include "Foo.h"

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
};
```

I get there is a circular reference because each .h includes the other, and the solution should be using **forward declarations**, but they don't seem to work, could someone explain why? I found similar problems here, and the solutions is always the same, I think I'm missing something :)

Comment: So ... where is your forward declaration?

Comment: If you want to use forward declaration of say `Bar` before `Foo` then `Bar bar;` is an error because compiler should know the size of `Bar` at that moment, but you can use an aggregation: `Bar* bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circular reference is entirely of your own making, and you can safely remove it by removing the `#include "Foo.h"` from Bar.h:

```
#pragma once

//#include "Foo.h"  <---- not necessary, Bar does not depend on Foo

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
};
```

You do not need a forward declaration of `Bar` inside `Foo.h`. A more general case would be if `Foo` and `Bar` were mutually dependent on each other, that would require forward declarations.

Comment: Sure, but I mean, if they are mutually dependent, how do you fix it?

Comment: @JoePerkins that would be the subject of another question, but typically you can have classes having pointers to each other like this: `class Foo; class Bar { Foo* f; }; class Foo { Bar* b; };`  But you cannot have classes that mutually contain non-pointer members of each other.

Comment: So the solution is to have a pointer instead. I totally missed that information while learning C++!